# Rounding numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, rounding

what is the best way to round commercial in javasript?

Example:

```
0.145 -> ToString(2) -> 0.14

mathjs:
math.round(0.145, 2)) -> 0.14
```

also math pow with round won´t work 100%

At the Moment i use:

```
function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    number = number + 0.000000001;
    number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');

    var n    = !isFinite(+number)   ? 0 : +number,
        prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
        sep  = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
        dec  = (typeof dec_point     === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
        s    = '',
        toFixedFix = function(n, prec) {
                         var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
                         return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
                     };

   // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
   s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');

   if (s[0].length > 3) 
   {
      s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
   }

   if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
     s[1]  = s[1] || '';
     s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
   }

   return s.join(dec);
}
```

With this fix ( number = number + 0.000000001;)
i get 0.15

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think the best approach is to convert the number to string, then look at the digits at the rounding position you want and one more and manually apply the rounding. I'll post a function soon.

Comment: *"Is there a better way to do it?"* Yes! Don't use floats for monetary computations. Keep the prices in the lowest units, e.g. cents. Then, when you want to display the number in a different unit (e.g. Euros) you just have to divide the value by 100.

Comment: can someone enlighten me about the word commercial in this question?

Comment: The Commercial rounds is as follows: 
If the digit in the first dropped decimal place a 0,1,2,3 or 4, then it is rounded. 
If the digit in the first dropped decimal place a 5,6,7,8 or 9, then it is rounded up.

Comment: The Mathematical (also geodetic or undistorted) Rounding is defined as follows:
Following the last digit to be retained is a 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4, it is rounded. 
Following the last digit to be retained a 5 (followed by further digits, which are not all zero), 6, 7, 8 or 9, it is rounded up. 
Following the last digit to be retained only a 5 (or 5, followed by all zeros), rounding is such that the last digit to be retained is straight.

Comment: That's just basic rounding, nothing commercial here. Try not to be too fancy with the terms you use.

Comment: in German it´s defined as "kaufmännisch runden". The Translator tells it´s commercially rounded

Comment: See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rundung#Kaufm.C3.A4nnisches_Runden

Comment: This is not a chatting field, keep your comments less in number and more in size. Also don't believe google translate, I bet it's a rounding technique of a kaufmann (merchant). Doesn't `Math.round()` work for you?

Comment: @Antony I can confirm that's the German word for the process, hence the confusion. I think we should remove the German references from the question, though.

Answer (score 1):

The rounding you mention is also called "banker's rounding", where if a number is to be rounded to n digits, then if the n+1 digit is 5 the nth digit is rounded to the nearest even number,

e.g. rounding to 2 places:

```
2.345 => 2.34
2.335 => 2.34
```

The following may suit, it's not thoroughly tested and has limits on the size of numbers that can be rounded, but it shows an approach. It's based on *toFixed* so returns a string.

```
function bankersRound(n, d) {
    var a, b;
    var p = String(n).split('.');

    if (p[1]) {
      a = p[1].substr(0, d);
      b = p[1].substr(d, 1);

      // If the d+1 character is 5 and the d character is even, force
      // toFixed to round down
      if (b == 5 && !(a%2)) {
          n = p[0] + '.' + a + '4';
      }
    }
    return Number(n).toFixed(d);
}

console.log(bankersRound(23.365, 2)); // 23.36
console.log(bankersRound(23.366, 2)); // 23.37
console.log(bankersRound(23.355, 2)); // 23.36
console.log(bankersRound(23.345, 2)); // 23.34
console.log(bankersRound(23.335, 2)); // 23.34
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round()` will do the job for you in integers. You can do a nice approach by multiplying your number by a power of 10, then round, then divide by the same number.

@Example: Decimal rounding
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

and a benchmark between them.

http://jsperf.com/roundingnumbers2

So my approach is faster than the others :), but not very safe for really big numbers

Answer (score 0):

If it is purely about formatting a currency value you can use a dedicated library like [`accounting.js`](http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/).

```
accounting.toFixed(0.615, 2); // "0.62"

accounting.formatMoney(12345678); // $12,345,678.00

accounting.formatMoney(4999.99, "€", 2, ".", ","); // €4.999,99
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity here is a technique dealing with integer division and even rounding is the technique discussed by [Daniel Lemire](https://lemire.me/blog/2020/04/16/rounding-integers-to-even-efficiently) and [Falk Hüffner](https://fpt.akt.tu-berlin.de/homepage-hueffner/):

```
function roundToEven(n, d) {
  var off = (n + d / 2)
  var roundup = off / d;
  var ismultiple = ((off % d) == 0);
  return (d | (roundup ^ ismultiple)) & roundup;
}

Math.round(3/2);
2
roundToEven(3,2);
2
```

> You may be concerned with overflows. Indeed, if both n and d are large, it is possible for n+d/2 to exceed to allowable range.